# adding a href class to javascript code?

Tags: javascript

Im using a jquery snippet to pull in a wordpress rss feed to my site. Im new to coding and pulled this together with some luck.

my question is how can I pass an href class="iframe" for code that looks like this?

```
rssoutput+="<li><a href='" + thefeeds[i].link + "'>" + thefeeds[i].title + "</a></li>"
```

thank you!

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
        //Examples of how to assign the ColorBox event to elements
        $(".group1").colorbox({rel:'group1'});
        $(".group2").colorbox({rel:'group2', transition:"fade"});
        $(".group3").colorbox({rel:'group3', transition:"none", width:"75%", height:"75%"});
        $(".group4").colorbox({rel:'group4', slideshow:true});
        $(".ajax").colorbox();
        $(".youtube").colorbox({iframe:true, innerWidth:425, innerHeight:344});
        $(".iframe").colorbox({iframe:true, width:"80%", height:"100%"});
        $(".inline").colorbox({inline:true, width:"50%"});
        $(".callbacks").colorbox({
            onOpen:function(){ alert('onOpen: colorbox is about to open'); },
            onLoad:function(){ alert('onLoad: colorbox has started to load the targeted content'); },
            onComplete:function(){ alert('onComplete: colorbox has displayed the loaded content'); },
            onCleanup:function(){ alert('onCleanup: colorbox has begun the close process'); },
            onClosed:function(){ alert('onClosed: colorbox has completely closed'); }
        });

        //Example of preserving a JavaScript event for inline calls.
        $("#click").click(function(){ 
            $('#click').css({"background-color":"#fff", "color":"#fff", "cursor":"inherit"}).text("Open this window again and this message will still be here.");
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Just add the class attribute to the string

```
rssoutput+="<li><a href='" + thefeeds[i].link + "' class='iframe'>" + thefeeds[i].title + "</a></li>"
```

**EDIT**

where the ID of your iframe is **myFrame**

```
rssoutput += "<li><a href='" + thefeeds[i].link + "' class='iframe' target='myFrame'>" + thefeeds[i].title + "</a></li>"
```

Comment: hmmm. doesnt seem to work. getting there though. the page opens outside of the iframe. iframes are working in other areas of the site

Comment: If you're wanting the link's resulting page to open in the same iframe, first give the iframe an ID and then target it in the link. See example in the edit above.

Comment: i feel like its close..im playing with it now.

Comment: @user1071890 - It's missing a closing `'` for the `href`. It should be after the 3rd `"` -- (snip) `thefeeks[i].link + "' class='iframe'>"`

Comment: how can i make the ID for the iframe? its generated in javascript dynamically? im sorry for my noobishness. maybe this is bigger than i thought

Comment: you would have to insert it into the string just like adding the class and target to the href string. We would need to see the code in order to show you specifically.

Comment: thanks for your help. i added the code above. is that where i would assign the ID?

Comment: you would assign the ID attribute onto the <iframe> tag, then reference that ID as the target for the href.

Comment: grrrrr. i should stick to graphic design

Comment: If you want to put up the entire code on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) or upload to [GITHub](http://github.com) I'll look at it a bit later

Answer (score 0):

Learn to do the less "stringy" code (the code where everything is done with string manipulation), but to use structured objects. If you use jQuery, you can as well use jquery-mochikit-tags project from github.com (finding it left as an exercise to the reader :-) ) and create html programmatically and using jQuery constructs like `append` or `appendTo` like this:

```
$.LI(
  $.A(
    {'href': thefeeds[i].link, 'class': 'iframe'},
    thefeeds[i].title
  )
).appendTo('#containerOfRssOutput');
```

Comment: thank you. i see what you are doing there but that is beyond my skills. im using a plugin written by someone else. just trying to fit it into my site.

Comment: If you see what am I doing here, then it is definitely not beyond your scope. :-) You should give it a try.